# how to know if session has ended and new session started using pcap data

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap, traffic

I have been working with pcap file. I am exploring it with scapy (Python). Now I don't know how to decide which packets belong to which tcp session. Which flags or bits should I check? I am not using Wireshark or any other tool. The only tool I can use is Scapy. My code is as follows:

```py
i=1
for packet in packets:
    print("Now serving details of Packet #### ", i)
    print("==============================")
    packet.show()
    i=i+1
    print("==============================")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think you would benefit from reviewing how TCP sessions work, with a video like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F27PLin3TV0).

Comment: You may also want to look at [Scapy TCP sessions](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.sessions.html#scapy.sessions.TCPSession)